# Function call statement in main function not actually calling the function

Tags: c++

1. The question is to find the largest subarray with contiguous
   elements. For example if the given array is **a[ ]={7,1,3,2}** then
   it's subarray would be **{1,3,2}** because the difference of maximum
   element and the minimum element is equal to the difference of the
   indexes of the first and the last element of the subarray and the
   subarray contains all the numbers between 1 and 3.
2. Here's a code that I have written for this problem but the thing is that in the main function somehow the function call line `longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray();` is not actually calling the function. I checked this in python tutor and it says that the whole program finished executing in only 1 step which should not be the case. So, can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

3.Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int Nmax= 100005;
int a[Nmax],n;
int longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray()
{   
    int ans = 1;
    for(int left = 0; left<(n-1) ; left++)
    {
        int Min, Max;
        Min=a[left];
        Max=a[left];
        for(int right = left+1 ; right<n ; right++)
        {
            Min = min(Min , a[right]);
            Max = max(Max , a[right]);
        
            if(Min-Max == right-left)
                ans = max(ans , Min-Max+1);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    cout<< longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray();
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I don't know why I had to indent my code with 4 spaces to get my code into the code block. I clicked on the code button and then I pasted the whole code but somehow all the tabs and spaces that were originally in my code disappeared.

Comment: A 4-space indent is how Stack Overflow (via Markdown) recognizes code. The other way is triple-backticks. Read the formatting help for more info.

Comment: What do you mean "not actually calling the function"? What does "Python tutor" have to do with C++ code? That function should be called presuming that `for` loop finishes without erroring out.

Comment: Note: C++ arrays are zero-indexed, that is the **first element is index 0**. You're starting these all at 1.

Comment: Can't reproduce: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7593491edc47f04f).

Comment: It's a limitation of the python tutor (on big loops ) which I don't see as a reliable compiler, let alone debugger.

Comment: try compiling using gcc and run this on a console in release mode, with several printf()'s for a quick debugging. If you still can't locate the problem, use a debugger and insert breakpoints.

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect. Of course the code in main calls the function `longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray`. Just try adding `cout << "got here\n"`; as the first line in the `longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray` function and you will see that it is being called..

Comment: @tadman python tutor helps to visualize the code written in python and other languages including cpp step by step.

Comment: @tadman i guess there is something wrong in my for loop. I changed all the starting point of the for loops to zero but the funtion still is returning one.

Comment: @anki that's why i reduced the size of the array but i still am getting one as answer.

Comment: Try adding `<< "\n"` after the call to `longestConsecutiveNumsSubarray()`.

Comment: @tadman i got the mistake. I wrote min-max instead of max-min. now the code is working perfectly fine